# Running Scrapy periodically from python results in ReactorAlreadyRunning

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted, reactor

After a few hours of tinkering and trying out snippets, I found in stackoverflow, I finally managed to run scrapy periodically:

```
timeout = 60.0 # seconds

class UrlCrawlerScript(Process):
    def __init__(self, spider):
        Process.__init__(self)
        settings = get_project_settings()
        self.crawler = Crawler(settings)

        if not hasattr(project, 'crawler'):
            self.crawler.install()
            self.crawler.configure()
            self.crawler.signals.connect(reactor.stop, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        self.spider = spider

    def run(self):
        self.crawler.crawl(self.spider)
        self.crawler.start()
        reactor.run()


def run_spider():
    spider = MarketSpider()
    crawler = UrlCrawlerScript(spider)
    crawler.start()
    crawler.join()
    print 'finished'


l = task.LoopingCall(run_spider)
l.start(timeout) # call every sixty seconds

reactor.run()
```

My problem is, that I still get `ReactorAlreadyRunning` after the second run.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Why not use [`scrapyd`](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) service?

Comment: The hosted enviroment doesn't allow running own processes.

Comment: Can you add the imports to your code so we can reusue it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that your program calls `reactor.run` in two places - and one of the places is called repeatedly, effectively in a loop (because it is called (indirectly) by `LoopingCall`).

Twisted's reactors are not restartable.  You can run and stop them once.  If you try to run them again, then you are given an exception.  If you try to run them while they're running, then you get another exception - `ReactorAlreadyRunning` - as you have seen.

The solution here is to run the reactor only once.  Consequently, you should stop the reactor only once as well.

At a minimum, this means you should only call `reactor.run` from one place in your program.  I suggest that, as a start, the call at the very end of the program is the one you want to keep and the one inside the `run` method (which will be called once each time you run the spider) should be eliminated.

You also need to avoid stopping the reactor when the spider is done.  If you connect `reactor.stop` to `spider_done` then after the spider runs the first time the reactor will stop and you won't be able to run the spider again.  I think you can simply delete this part of your program.

Comment: I actually already solved the problem by stripping the program down to it's bare minimum. Yes, it boils down to avoiding calling reactor.run() only once.

Comment: Not to "avoiding calling reactor.run() only once".  :)